# How can I install Likewise-open in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, dpkg, likewise

```
$ sudo apt-get install likewise-open
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package likewise-open
```

Answer (score 3):

UGH I hate that they stick that stupid info collection wall in front of you. Here is the URL to bypass their stupidity. Not sure why Terndon deleted this the first time. This is a direct link to the Powerbroker free install without having to give up all your personal info. It's not a protected link, it is not copyrighted and it is just a git link. Please do not delete it again. I am hoping this will help folks. I fell on the sword and gave up personal info to get this.

https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/releases

Answer (score 1):

Likewise Open was purchased in 2012 by BeyondTrust software and renamed to PowerBroker Identity Services Open: http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/

This project does support Ubuntu. There is a hidden "--oem oem1" build      switch that looks to use Ubuntu-preferred paths, instead of "/opt/pbis".      This should be investigated as a replacement.

According to the [redirect web page](https://www.beyondtrust.com/powerbroker-identity-services-open-request/) there is a "free and open source" version available for download. It appears that registration is required.

**Sources:**

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/likewise-open/+bug/1295031/comments/8

https://www.beyondtrust.com/powerbroker-identity-services-open-request/

Answer (score 0):

This package only exist on Ubuntu `precise` and simply you can't install it on `17.04 : zesty`.

*Although here is a bad idea:*

You can grab a copy of old and outdated `deb` files from here:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/likewise-open/likewise-open_6.1.0.406-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Then use:

```
sudo dpkg -i likewise-open_6.1.0.406-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

To install it, worked for me on `16.04`.

However I strongly suggest you to search for an alternative and not using this outdated package which has no support.